# List in QueryDict retrieved as string

Tags: django

I re-construct my code as minimal as:

```
<form action="#" method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <textarea name="content" id="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    <input type="text" name="tags">
    <input type="submit">   
</form>
```

I print the POST data from views.py

```
print(self.request.POST)
print(self.request.POST["title"])
print(self.request.POST["content"])
print(self.request.POST["tags"])
print(type(self.request.POST["tags"]))
```

Come by with

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['r4QIefk3YNSU0EivHwq8dwmHUNPFK4WwcvJyt5FK6gAQUdTl6IJ2m8V1Z71OZ1kU'], 'title': ['list'], 'content': ['display'], 'tags': ['as,string']}>
list
but
as,string
<class 'str'>
```

Within QueryDict, they are lists of `['list']` `['display']` `['as,string']`

but is retrieved as string.

What's happening here?

Comment: Well a querydict acts like a dictionary,, in case of a lookup like `request.POST[key]` it provides the *last* element. But you can use `getlist` to retrieve all elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QueryDict` is subclass of [`MultiValueDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/utils/datastructures/) which allows to handle multiple values for the same key. By default MultiValueDict's `__getitem__` method returns last element in list . 
But as @WillemVanOnsem said in his comment `MultiValueDict` also provides `getlist` method which returns all values associated with selected key.